# Apache won't start after enabling SSL for XAMPP

Tags: windows, apache, ssl, xampp

I am running XAMPP v3.2.1 on windows 7. I had it running on port 80 and accessable from my network with no issues.

However, when I attempted to enable SSL Apache won't start.

Here is what I did to enable SSL for Appache

I opened a file called `https-vhosts.conf` file located at `F:\xamp\apache\extra`

and changed the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs/proj1"
    ServerAdmin test@localhost.com
    ServerName server1.domain.com
    ServerAlias server1.domain.com

    <Directory "F:/xampp/htdocs/proj1">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

to

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs/proj1"
    ServerAdmin test@localhost.com
    ServerName server1.domain.com
    ServerAlias server1.domain.com

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "F:/xampp/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "F:/xampp/conf/ssl.key/server.key"


    <Directory "F:/xampp/htdocs/proj1">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I did not change another files or settings beside the mentioned above.

This is what I got in the XAMPP control panel

```
11:24:25 AM  [Apache]   Attempting to start Apache app...
11:24:25 AM  [Apache]   Status change detected: running
11:24:26 AM  [Apache]   Status change detected: stopped
11:24:26 AM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
11:24:26 AM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:24:26 AM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:24:26 AM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:24:26 AM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:24:26 AM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
11:24:26 AM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

What did I miss? 
How can I correct the issue and enable SSL?

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work. I had the wrong path for the certs

here is how my vhost looks like now

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs/proj1"
    ServerAdmin test@localhost.com
    ServerName server1.domain.com
    ServerAlias server1.domain.com

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"

    <Directory "F:/xampp/htdocs/proj1">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```